# Magento2 reset shipping methods?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

What i want that,when customer goes on checkout page generally select shipping method but if he came back to cart then again go to checkout in that case shipping should be reset.

But Magento 2 generally do,it keeps the data in cache when we go to checkout then if again come back then it load from there.

Could any one know about this how we can approach it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the shipping method as :

Go to `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-address\shipping-method-list.phtml`

and replace the `line 10` code from

```
<input type="radio"
               class="radio"
               ifnot="method.error_message"
               ko-checked="element.isSelected"
               ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
               attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                    'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
```

To :

```
<input type="radio"
               class="radio"
               ifnot="method.error_message"
               ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
               attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code" />
```

And run the `php bin\magento setup:upgrade` command.

`Note :` Override the file in your theme, do not change directly in the core file.